# Visibility of element- selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My script creates a new article: fills few fields and click "Submit button" at end of page.

I have written `Click()` function in `util` class like :

```
public void click(String xpathKey)
{
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
      .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
               By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty(xpathKey))));

    try
    {
        myDynamicElement.click();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Waiting for visibility of element means it will wait until element will be visible on the page or on screen? My script clicks on submit button while it's not exactly visible on the page.

I am running this script since months and it's running perfectly fine. Suddenly it started giving error element is not clickable at point(213, 415). It never appeared before. Anyone has an idea, why it could have happened?

I have done many cases, where the element is not exactly visible, generally button at end of page. selenium does not scroll itself, it finds the element and performs operation.

Comment: change the condition to clickable rather than visibility and see if it's working.

Comment: Hi Gaurang, i changed it to elementToBeClickable but it did not help. Its giving same error: element not clcikable at (282, 706).

Comment: could you share the html of the element as well, surely something has changed in the source, the best thing would be to check revision of application code or talk to dev.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty(xpathKey))`

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, earlier i was using xpath but now replaced all xpath with CSS in property file. So this is correct for sure.

Comment: A quick way to indentify this issue, it's sleep 15-20ss  before click , if the script worked, means your wait is not enough.  change your wait.

Comment: this issue should be caused click occur when page is still changing. so the center point of the element is always moving, selenium use the old location: point(213, 415) to dirver click, but now there is another element at the old location. after click on the old location, selenium detect the new element is not clickable.

Comment: I added Thread.sleep() for 10 seconds and it worked. But i am not able to understand : 1. i have given explicit wait for 60 sec for element to be clickable. What explicit condition i need to give because using thread.sleep is not a great idea. 2. Also, i am running same script since 4 months. I never faced this issue before. I made sure with developers, no changes are made in UI. Suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: When posting questions, please post the full error message that you are getting. It's helpful in figuring out what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting indicates that there is an element covering the element you are trying to click. If you read the error message carefully, it will tell you the HTML of the blocking element and that will help you find it on the page. Without more info, it's hard to tell exactly what the situation is but there are a few common causes.

1. You may have just closed a dialog/popup and it's not quite completely gone before you try to click. In this case, wait for some element that's part of the dialog to be invisible generally solves this problem.
2. There may be some wait/loading/spinner control that appears and disappears but you are clicking before it's completely gone. The solution is the same as #1, wait for some element that's part of the spinner to be invisible.
3. There may be some UI element like a header, footer, sidebar that is floating that covers the element you are trying to click if it's at the very bottom/top/etc of the page. These can be a real pain because you never know when the elements are going to align and be covered. One solution is to use JS to scroll the page a little more. For example, if you script is at the top of the page and you want to click something at the bottom. Doing a click will scroll the page to show that element but that puts the element at the very bottom of the page and under a floating footer. You try to click but catch the exception. Since you know you're at the bottom of the page, you scroll the page downwards by X pixels. This brings your desired element out from behind the floating footer and now you can click it.

NOTE: If you are going to click an element right after waiting for it, you should use `.elementToBeClickable(locator)` instead of `.visibilityOfElementLocated()`. It won't solve your current problem but it's a more complete and proper wait for what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public void click(String xpathKey)
{
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
      .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
               By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty(xpathKey))));

    try
    {
         Actions act = new Actions(driver);
         act.moveToElement(myDynamicElement);
         act.click();
         act.build().perform();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```